# Platform Event - Subscribe from a Flow and pass to aura

Tags: visual-workflow, aura, platform-event

Is there a mechanism to subscribe to platform events from a flow 'and' pass attributes to a lightning component - when a new event is delivered (basically synchronously).
Already have tried the normal EMP API in Lightning components, however hitting Platform event daily delivered limits.
The use case is -  when a new record on a custom object is created - we want to get a notification on a custom lightning component.

Comment: Then I guess it's time to upgrade, contact Salesforce.

Comment: the max even after update is 150K

Comment: Are we really creating this many records, else a code review can highlight the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you will exceed standard PE limits?

If you need to increase the PE or DC limit you can contact salesforce ask for an additional license cost.

If you can afford 2 to 3 min of delay you can try asynchronous schedule apex call based on the last created date. A simple js timer function can help.

Comment: Cannot increase more limits sadly. This needs to be near real time. A record gets created (quire frequently), the aura component must get a notification. Hence used Platform events and EMP API in the first place

Comment: then I am afraid salesforce is not the right platform to do this, or you can wait to build a salesforce function which is in beta right now.